# two network configurations in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking

I have two Ubuntu Desktop boxes that use a wireless interface to connect to a Wifi network I have no control of i.e. DNS, protocols, authentication etc. Now I would like to have a direct cable connection between these two boxes and configure it so that they have high speed direct cable connection and "can see each other" directly and not through the WiFi network.

Can anyone advice what's the best way to do that? references/pointers to where to find the information also appreciated!

UPDATE: when I connect the two machines I see the `Wired Connection 1` connected. Now trying to communicate with each other I choose "Edit connections..." then choose "IPv4 Settings" tab and now I have to add but this should add the IP addresses I should be able to access and not my own IP address for the eth0 interface. Can you please explain in more detail how this is done?

Comment: Do you want them to be able to access the internet wirelessly?  Or do you want the wireless disabled?

Comment: internet is accessed through the wireless. I need the direct connection for fast communication between these two nodes.

Comment: Do you have config access to the WAP?

Comment: If you mean to the configurations in these two machines yes, I dont have access to the configuration settings of the wireless router though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try by changing the route table.  For reference see this link:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialNetworking.html#ROUTE

The section you want is "Dynamic Routes" for editing the RIP.  The specific command your looking for should be:

```
route add -host 1.1.1.1 eth1
```

Where 1.1.1.1 is the IP address of the host you want to connect to, and eth1 is the ethernet connection designated.

Comment: Note that you will have to do that on both hosts (with the correct IP per host).

Comment: Aren't the IP addresses 1.1.1.1 in use in internet? I should use 10.x.x.x instead no?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua  That IP was used just as a placeholder.  You'd want to substitute the real IP.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, there's a copper based nic card available. If they are 1G ready, usually any copper RJ45 cable will do. If they are 100M or below, you need a cross over RJ45 cable.

Simply connect your boxes with such a cable. Then configure each box with IP address in RFC1918 range , e.g. 10.10.10.0/31 and 10.10.10.1/31 respectively. Then you are good to go. Just access 10.10.10.0 from 10.10.10.1 or vice versa.

Comment: What do I fill in in IP Mask, Gateway and Broadcast addresses?

Comment: /31, or 255.255.255.254, is IP mask.
Gateway/broadcast address is not necessary.

use this command: